# Create a bold image in css at hover?

Tags: css

I have a css style something like:

```
.button {background:#e9e9e9 url('/image.png') no-repeat 9px 12px;}
.button:hover {background:#e9e9e9 url('/bold-image.png') no-repeat 9px 12px;}
```

Is there a way to skip above `:hover` part and make the image.png "bolder" (a bold effect of the original image)? (without having to create an image for it)

Comment: Define `bold effect` please.

Comment: Did not get your question. You mean by default you want to make the image bolder but without creating another PNG? I am afraid that wouldn't be possible with CSS.

Comment: When hovering I want the image to be thicker/bolder in some sense when hovering it (without creating an image for it). Is this possible in css?

For example: Let's say you the letter A in font-weight:normal, and when you hover it you change it to font-weight:bold ... Something similiar like that but with an image.

Comment: @Harry - Yes, I meant that.

Comment: No it's not possible, 'cause its image. If you want to achieve effect like this, create a custom tag/partial view/just copy-paste/whatever to display your html: div with its styles

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: As I said earlier editing/altering the contents of an image would not be possible with CSS pal. You would have to use other means.

Comment: @Harry while true, there *is* a way to fake the effect by pure CSS. But the browser support is limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is not possible to alter the content of images by CSS. However in this particular case, we can fake the **bold effect** of the contents by using [`drop-shadow` filter](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/#funcdef-drop-shadow) *(assuming the image is transparent and there is **no** background color attached!)*:

```css
.button {
    background: url('/image.png') no-repeat 9px 12px;
}

.button:hover {
    background: url('/image.png') no-repeat 9px 12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px black); /* webkit only 
                     assuming the content is written in black */
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px black);              /* FF~35 */
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 8px black);              /* MDN */
}
```

As can be seen, the [browser support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) to Webkit-based web browsers and Firefox 35+ as of writing.

Here is an online example:

```css
.button-container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.button {
  width: 488px;
  height: 198px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  
  background: url('http://overshoot.tv/sites/overshoot.tv/files/black-on-transparent.png') no-repeat 9px 12px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: url('http://overshoot.tv/sites/overshoot.tv/files/black-on-transparent.png') no-repeat 9px 12px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px black); /* webkit only 
                 assuming the content is written in black */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px black);            /* FF~35 */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 5px black);            /* MDN */
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button"></button>
</div>
```

Webkit-based web browsers and also Firefox 35 don't seem to support the syntax stated by [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()), however let's leave it at there for upcoming web browsers.

Comment: So cool, BUT this sets an drop-shadow to the button - element not the image itself. +1 for this solution though!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Just added a demo and fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) I really didn't think this would be possible :-)

Comment: @HashemQolami: That was a real gem :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like zoom effect?

Try

```
img:hover {zoom:120%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `background-size` property will let you scale the image in just one direction, which may or may not look ugly, but from your snippet, I'm not sure if you're using a sprite there, where there might be more number-fiddling involved than it's worth. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) is de facto universal.

```css
.button {
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff&text=Send');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}
.button:hover {
  background-size: 105% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a style="display:inline-block;width:400px;height:200px;" class="button">...</a>
```